# How to edit svn externals of a folder using powershell

Tags: powershell, svn, externals

In order to do a build, I checkout a svn repository which has multiple folders.One of folders has properties -> svn externals pointing to a particular tag number, I need to edit the svn externals to point to a different tag number. I want to pass this new tag number as a parameter. How can I achieve this using powershell.

Answer (score 0):

```
svn propset svn:externals "folder_name http://path_to_tag" .
```

Note the trailing dot.

You can read a bit more about Externals Definitions [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html).

Comment: I have idea about how to set svn externals. What I am trying to do is how to edit using powershell. Out of all the checked out folders, only one has svn externals in it. I need to reach that one particular folder and edit svn externals. How can I achieve this using powershell. I have idea about the svn commands

Comment: "I need to reach that one particular folder and edit svn externals. How can I achieve this using powershell." - If you execute this command in PowerShell, you will edit externals property of desired folder. This command is sufficient for your task.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. My folder structure is: OuterFolder has two svn externals
1. FolderA pointing to repositoryA/tags/1.0
2. FolderB pointing to repositoryB/tags/2.0

I want them to change to 
1. FolderA pointing to repositoryA/tags/1.1
2. FolderB pointing to repositoryB/tags/2.1

I tried like below... but they are not updated.


`svn propset svn:externals "OuterFolder/FolderA https://repositoryA/tags/1.1" .`


`svn propset svn:externals "OuterFolder/FolderB https://repositoryB/tags/2.1" .`

Am I doing right ?

Comment: "but they are not updated." - `svn:externals` property is not updated? After executing your commands, what do you get when execute: `svn propget svn:externals`